# A supmodule of a generator is a generator

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I would like to prove that given a supmodule $M \in {}_A\text{Mod}$ of a generator $N \in {}_A\text{Mod}$ is a generator.

I want to do the following:

I know that $N$ is a generator is equivalent to the evaluation map $$ev:N\otimes_A{}^*N\rightarrow A:n\otimes_Af\mapsto f(n)$$
is surjective. I want to prove similar result for $M$.

Take $a\in A$. Then there exists $n\otimes_Af \in N\otimes_A{}^*N$ s.t. $f(n) = p$. I would like to extend $f$ to $M$ then I am finished. But how to do that?

If I can define a "projection" $\pi$ of $M$ unto $N$ then composing $\pi\circ f$ gives a map in ${}^*M$ s.t. $(f\circ\pi)(n) = p$ and I am finished.

How do I define such a projection or is this not at all the right way to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

This is false.  For instance, if $A=\mathbb{Z}$, then $N=\mathbb{Z}$ is a generator, but it is a submodule of $M=\mathbb{Q}$, which is not a generator.